# tests skipped inspite the dependant method passed. TestNG

Tags: annotations, testng

I have a number of tests across classes. Each class is defined as @Test and group name added to it same as class name[they are u1,u2,u3,u4,u5]. 
In u1, I have a test method for prerequisites called prereqSetup(). This is added to the group "prereq".
Now, all the methods in u1 are marked with dependsOnMethods="prereqSetup".
Rest all classes are marked as dependsOnGroups="prereq".

My prerequisites method has passed. Couple of methods in u1 and u3 are run and show failed. 
But rest all methods are skipped. There is no other dependency apart from what i have mentined above. Providing the annotations for reference:

```
@Test(groups="u1")
public class U1 {
//All methods are marked with @Test(dependsOnMethods="prereqSetup")
}

@Test(groups="u2",dependsOnGroups="prereq")
public class U2{
//All methods are marked with @Test
}
```

This is done for all classes through u2-u5.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unclear on the question but it doesn't look like you have a group called "prereq"

Comment: turns out it was a prob with our org framework. Sorry for the trouble.