# Test method is skipped even though the dependsOnGroups method is passed

Tags: testng

I have the following structure in testng.xml

```
<test name="test">
<groups>
<run>
<include name ="E"/>
<include name ="Sanity"/>
</run>
<groups/>
<classes>
<class name="com.test.testcases.Test2"/>
<class name="com.test.testcases.Test1"/>
</classes>
</test>
```

Test2 belongs to group Sanity and Test1 belongs to group E. The test method in group "Sanity" depends on the test method in group "E". I have used dependsOnGroups as both the methods are in different classes. Now, on running the suite, I see that the test method in Test2 is skipped even though Test1 has passed. Could anyone help in this regard?

Comment: Looks ok... you may try to make a SSCCE and post the code.

Comment: I believe there is no issue with the code inside the class files. Probably something that I am missing in testng.xml which is causing this.

Comment: Same question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445344/tests-skipped-inspite-the-dependant-method-passed-testng?rq=1

Comment: Could you set verbose to 10 and share the output? `<suite name="..." verbose="10" >`

Comment: @JulienHerr - That helped bigtime. There was an error in the dataprovider name that was given for the skipped method which was not shown earlier. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the dataprovider name that was given for the skipped method which was not shown earlier.